# MappedbyteBuffer.get() increments position by too much

Tags: java, increment, memory-mapped-files, mappedbytebuffer

The relevant part of my file is this:

```
82 0a 96 c9 82 0a 96 d3 00 66 13 08
```

I open the file in a mappedbytebuffer and set the position to the beginning. Then I do this:

```
MappedByteBuffer buffer = channel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, channel.size());
...
buffer.position(packetInfos.get(idPacket).getStartPos());

//getting the time from the packet header
time = Math.addExact(Math.multiplyExact((long) buffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getInt(), 1000), Math.floorDiv(buffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getInt(), 1000));

//getting the source ip from the ip frame
buffer.position(packetInfos.get(idPacket).getStartPos() + PACKET_IPSOURCE_OFFS); // puts the buffers position at the part of the file shown above
source = byteToUnsigned(buffer.get()) + "." + byteToUnsigned(buffer.get()) + "." + byteToUnsigned(buffer.get()) + "." + byteToUnsigned(buffer.get());

//getting the destination ip from the ip frame
destination = byteToUnsigned(buffer.get()) + "." + byteToUnsigned(buffer.get()) + "." + byteToUnsigned(buffer.get()) + "." + byteToUnsigned(buffer.get());
```

The byteToUnsigned method simply does:

```
public static int byteToUnsigned(byte b){
    return b & 0xFF;
}
```

source ends up being: "130.10.150.211" when it should be "130.10.150.201".
For some reason the get() method increments the position of the buffer by 1 in most cases, but by 5 after the third time? As you might have guessed I'm trying to decode the destination ip afterwards and it starts reading after the "D3", resulting in "0.102.19.8"

---

Even before the byteToUnsigned calls the source Ip is "-126.10.-106.-45".

---

After debugging step by step through this line:

```
source = byteToUnsigned(buffer.get()) + "." + byteToUnsigned(buffer.get()) + "." + byteToUnsigned(buffer.get()) + "." + byteToUnsigned(buffer.get());
```

Watching buffer.position() and buffer.get(), I could see the following:

- first get():  buffer.position()=70, buffer.get()=-126
- second get(): buffer.position()=71, buffer.get()=10
- third get():  buffer.position()=72, buffer.get()=-106
- fourth get(): buffer.position()=**73**, buffer.get()=-45

So the position is incremented correctly, but the bytes between the 72nd and the 77th are not visible to the buffer somehow?

---

The Api plainly states:

```
public abstract byte get()
Relative get method. Reads the byte at this buffer's current position, and then increments the position.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Well, either there's a critical bug in Java, or you have other code that does something that moves the position.

Comment: Where would I do that? There's no additional code between the two get() calls. Also, the buffer is created in that function and the exact error can be reproduced.

Comment: Second question in a row that seems to get no attention. What could I do differently when explaining my issue?

Comment: There are no guarantees on SO. The problematic thing with this question is that it says `get()` moves position more than `1` byte (which you know can't really be true). Now since it's unlikely that there is a bug in `MappedByteBuffer`, the most likely reason is a bug in your code. It's also not unheard of that people write *different* code in the question than what they're actually running (for some reason they avoid copy pasting), so people waste time trying to debug the wrong code. I'd recommend going step-by-step in a debugger, and if you can verify a bug, file a bug report.

Comment: I admit the question title was meant to be a bit of an eye catcher, and I promise the code I posted is line for line what I am actually using. But alright, I will debug more and try to find the problem with my code by myself.

Comment: Yeah, I was just explaining how the thousands of questions that go through here get "handled". You've got duplicates (how do I compare Strings), bad students (here's my homework assignment), people trying to bite more than they can chew (I *want* to create a MMORPG), then you got a lot of simple mistakes that can be solved with a cursory glance, and sometimes you have more advanced/interesting questions that get attention because they're interesting. Then you have the ones that fall through the gaps and don't get closed or answered, like this one. It's nothing personal.

Comment: I absolutely understand. I didn't think you were accusing me of anything nor am I entitled enough to think my questions deserve the most attention.  This'll be my last comment on the subject, I know comments are not meant for discussion.

Comment: I think the most likely explanation is that this code: `buffer.position(packetInfos.get(idPacket).getStartPos() + PACKET_IPSOURCE_OFFS);` is not positioning the buffer where you think it is, and you are simply reading the second IP address instead of the first.  Note that the first three bytes of both are exactly the same.

Comment: You've supplied twelve bytes of data, and code that reads 16 bytes: two `ints` and twice four bytes.

Comment: msandiford you are absolutely right, I noticed that a second ago myself. If you want to post it as an answer again I'll accept it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out I'm an enormous idiot. I did not notice the bytes 82 0a 96 repeat just a few bytes to the right. Which is where I accidentally placed the position of the buffer. Don't worry, I'm ashamed.